# Which quadrant contains no solutions to the system..

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

I need help for this question. There is definitely a solution in the 3rd quadrant since the two equation do intersect each other there.

If the system of inequalities

```
   y>= 2x+1 and y > 0.5x-1 is graphed in the xy-plane below,
```

which quadrant contains no solutions to the system.

```
                 ^y axis
                 |
         II      |  I
  _______________|___________ > x axis
                 |
      III        |  IV
                 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Every quadrant other than quadrant 4 contains a solution to these. Examples in quadrants 1-3:

Quadrant 1: (1,4)

Quadrant 2: (-2,7)

Quadrant 3: (-3,-1)

The reason why quadrant 4 does not contain any solutions is because $y \geq 2x+1$ has no solutions in the fourth quadrant. We can prove this as follows: Let (x,y) be in the fourth quadrant. Thus, $x > 0$. If $(x,y)$ satisfies $y \geq 2x+1$, then $y \geq 1$. But $y\geq1$ does not belong to the fourth quadrant. Hence by contraction, no point in the fourth quadrant satisfies this inequality.